# Cannot add a RelativeLayout to a RelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

So I'm trying to add a RelativeLayout to a RelativeLayout however, when I run my app, it's an IllegalStateException that shows this error: *The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.* I'm sure you guys have seen this before. My question is how do I properly nest two relative layouts together?

Here is the code snippet that produces the exception:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    RelativeLayout newFrame = new RelativeLayout(vidRipperService.getBaseContext());
    newFrame.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    // configure image view constraints...
    // have the frame be right in the center of the layout.
    ImageView editedFrame = new ImageView(vidRipperService.getBaseContext());
    // Note: when doing padding the height and the width must be a multiple of two. A nice example is 70+30 = 100/2 = 50, but 80+30 = 110/2 = 55 <- not a multiple of two. Keep this in mind.
    editedFrame.setId(View.generateViewId());
    editedFrame.setPadding(30,30,30,0); // padding of 30 around the whole view.
    editedFrame.setImageBitmap(frame); // set the frame to be that of the actual background.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    frameLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); // place frames in center of the view.

    editedFrame.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutParams);

    newFrame.addView(breakingNewsLayout); // add the breaking news layout to this view!
    newFrame.addView(editedFrame);
```

The problem is specifically triggered from the second to last line **newFrame.addView(breakingNewsLayout)**  That line triggers the exception. The breakingNewsLayout is another relative layout that I would like to add to newFrame. I would appreciate any knowledge on how to get this to work. I never ran into a problem when nesting layouts before, but for some reason, this is really not playing nice.

Here is the code that creates the breakingNewsLayout:

```
private void createBreakingNewsLayout()
{
    breakingNewsLayout = new RelativeLayout(vidRipperService.getBaseContext()); // create the new breaking new layout.
    breakingNewsLayout.setElevation(5);
    breakingNewsLayout.setPadding(0,0,0,15);
    breakingNewsLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(vidRipperService, R.color.transparent)); // ensure that the background is transparent.

    // MATCH_PARENT for both width and height so that banner is shown on the frame for the video.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams breakingNewsParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    breakingNewsParams.setMargins(0,50,0,0); // todo: ensure that the margin is 50dp not pixels!
    breakingNewsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    breakingNewsLayout.setLayoutParams(breakingNewsParams); // set the layout params for the breaking news layout.

    // set all of the text view attributes.
    TextView liveBannerText = getLiveBannerText();
    TextView breakingNewsTime = getBreakingNewsTime();
    TextView breakingNewsHeadline = getBreakingNewsHeadline(breakingNewsTime.getId()); // headline goes about the breaking news time.
    TextView breakingNewsBanner = getBreakingNewsBanner(breakingNewsHeadline.getId()); // banner goes above the breaking news headline
    TextView viddyWatermarkText = getViddyWatermarkText(breakingNewsHeadline.getId()); // viddy watermark goes above the breaking news headline.
    TextView breakingNewsDescription = getBreakingNewsDescription(breakingNewsTime.getId()); // breaking news description goes to the end of the breaking news time

    // Add all of the views for the breaking news layout.
    breakingNewsLayout.addView(liveBannerText);
    breakingNewsLayout.addView(breakingNewsBanner);
    breakingNewsLayout.addView(viddyWatermarkText);
    breakingNewsLayout.addView(breakingNewsHeadline);
    breakingNewsLayout.addView(breakingNewsTime);
    breakingNewsLayout.addView(breakingNewsDescription);
}
```

Comment: It returns null... I confess I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should remove `breakingNewsLayout` before you add it:

```
((ViewGroup) breakingNewsLayout.getParent()).removeView(breakingNewsLayout);
```

Comment: I thought that this was the case to, but unfortunately it is not quite what the program is looking for. This is the first time I've added breakingNewsLayout to the parent layout.

Comment: can you post the code where you create the `breakingNewsLayout`

Comment: BreakingNewsLayout code as been added as requested!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! After extensive researching and testing the reason I was getting this issue was because I was attempting to reuse the breakingNewsLayout when creating a new frame. I have x amount of frames and I needed to generate the breakingNewsLayout every single time I wanted to apply the layout to the frame. Since I was trying to reuse the layout that I have already added, the layout already has a parent and thus the exception above was called.

Apologies for the question and any lack of details.